# Why I cannot seem to get a good image in 360p Youtube?

Tags: video-quality, youtube, camera, compression, canon

This is a Canon M50 4K footage [manual focus] using Kit-lens, using very fast shutter speed around 1/300, ISO around 400, and Aperture f/4. (No edit just straight from the memory card)

This is another one that is better looking (flower):

Viewed at 360p it looks so terrible compared to other Youtube videos that only used smartphones.

I already tried to export with very high bit rate like 120Mb/s and even higher than that, but it does not seem to ameliorate the Youtube compression on my video.

Does wider Aperture really matter on the picture quality? even though I already set very low ISO less than 500. I can see that Thomas Vennet's video using Canon M50 looks good even in 360p, he was using wider aperture lens f2.8.
(

)